# Drilldown different chart types leave artifacts when drilling up?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I'm doing a chart with three drilldowns, the first and second drills will draw a pie-chart and the last drill should draw a column chart instead. All of that works fine but I noticed that (at least in chrome) when you drillup, pieces of the column chart still persist behind the pie-chart, namely the Y-axis label and the x-axis plot line.

Is there anything I can do about this ?

```
$(function () {

// Create the chart
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Basic drilldown'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category'
    },

    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            borderWidth: 0,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Things',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'Animals',
            y: 5,
            drilldown: 'animals'
        }]
    }],
    drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'animals',
            name: 'Animals',
            data: [{
                name: 'Cats',
                y: 4,
                drilldown: 'cats'
            }, ['Dogs', 2],
                ['Cows', 1],
                ['Sheep', 2],
                ['Pigs', 1]
            ]
        }, {

            id: 'cats',
            data: [1, 2, 3],
            type: "column"
        }]
    }
})
});
```

[Here is a fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/6LXVQ/99/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `showEmpty: false` for both axes. [Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mx9un9o6/)